# How to dynamically create a view and add on main view in android?

Tags: android

I am newbie to android (on mac using eclipse). Please let me know how to create a view dynamically and add it to main view.

Context:

Actually I want to show a view of processing on the main screen when user has performed any action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your main view is a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and you already have an instance of it the code would look something like this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
textView.setText("Processing...");
mainView.addView(textView);
```