# Android how to link xml with button?

Tags: android

I know how to screen1.xml to screen2.xml, with onClick method in my .java. But isit possible for me to just redirect to a xml with just ? I mean without anything in .java. Because i am about to have alot of xml layout with button linked to one xml.

Screen1 button > screen5

Screen2 button > screen5

Screen3 button > screen5

Screen4 button > screen5

and so on, i might have like 100over layouts link to screen5 so if i can just done everything in xml without needed to create .java for each of them could do me a big favour.

Comment: can you modify the question to make it clear, little bit confusing now.

Comment: Example, layout1.xml to layout2.xml. 
And layout2 back to layout1 with button. 
We have onClick method for buttons in xml right ? So layout1.java has onClick for button, so does layout2.java.

What im trying to do is, having layout2 - layout50 to have button that leads me to layout1. So must i create layout2.java - layout50.java ?

Comment: so you should not write onClick for all buttons but you have to achieve that, correct ? i will try it give some time, now  i am busy with other work. ok. bye

Comment: Yes. It will saves me alot time without needing to implement 50 onclick for 50 xml. Ok.

Comment: how you are using all these layouts ? each layout as one activity or all in single activity ?

Comment: all these xml layout will only has one single button, and the same function which led to one layout displaying webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need onClick on your buttons

```
 <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

then implement the method `selfDestruct()` in your Activity:

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     // Kabloey
 }
```

Comment: in where i have to implement selfDestruct() method ? and for having so many layout with each of them using <Button> do i have to create .java for all of them?

Comment: Only one selfDestruct(), that's why you receive the clicked view as a parameter.

Comment: suppose your buttons are
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />

<Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />

then add below code in selfDestruct method
switch(view.getId()){
case R.id.btn1:
//add btn1 code
 break;
case R.id.btn2:
//add btn2 code 
break;
}

Answer (score 1):

This example show how to dynamically create a view and add on main view. For you problem, only replace view for button:

[How to dynamically create a view and add on main view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568623/how-to-dynamically-create-a-view-and-add-on-main-view-in-android)

Another alternative, is to use the include tag:

[Using "merge" and "include"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156010/using-merge-and-include)